# Console Input from Windows Form Controls

Tags: c#, input, process, console

I am creating an application that receives output from a console and displays it in a more user friendly view through a list box using windows forms. I've done this by starting the process of a .jar file and using this code:

```
 public void DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // e.Data is the line which was written to standard output
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            // textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + e.Data; });
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { listBox1.Items.Add(e.Data); }));
        }
    }
    public void StartServer()
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java", @"-Xmx1024M -jar " + UltimateMinecraftServerCreator.Properties.Settings.Default.jarname);
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = UltimateMinecraftServerCreator.Properties.Settings.Default.jarlocator;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.OutputDataReceived += DataReceived;
        p.Start();
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    }
```

I'm wondering if on this same form if it would be possible to allow users to click buttons that will send a command to the console as well as them being able to type commands if they know them.

Thanks!

Comment: Its not very clear, do you have 2 applications? one is windows forms and other one is console application? or you have only win-forms app and run it from command line?

Comment: Sorry! Basically I have a windows forms application that I've created and I'm running a .jar file through my application and receiving output from it into a list box, however I want to be able to invoke the running server and allow data to be outputted to it. So in essence, it essentially does run like a console but I didn't make it (the .jar file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally worked it out! Was pretty simple really, I moved the declaration of Process p above all the controls code so it became universal and was able to use p.StandardInput.WriteLine("");